# How to get full name of an employee by joining first, middle and last name considering null in java

Tags: java

Here is the employee class and I have to write a method which gives full name of the employee by concatenating `firstName`, `middleName` and `lastName` considering null and empty string.

```
public class Employee {
   private String firstName;
   private String middleName;
   private String lastName;

   // Setters and getters

   public String getFullName(){
       // What code should I write here
   }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the point of this question? just to show off your solution?

Comment: This might be a good place to introduce the cool `Optional`, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html

Answer (score 12):

Filter out nulls and empty strings and concatenate them into full name:

```
public String getFullName() {
    return Stream.of(firstName, middleName, lastName)
        .filter(x - > x != null && !x.isEmpty())
        .collect(joining(" "));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative if you are not using Stream:

```
public String getFullName(){
    firstName = firstName!=null?firstName:"";
    middleName = middleName!=null?middleName:"";
    lastName = lastName!=null?lastName:"";

    return (firstName + " " + middleName + " " + lastName).trim();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Shashank K's answer is nice. But something simple to understand:

```
public class Employee{
   private String firstName;
   private String middleName;
   private String lastName;

   //setters and getters
   public String getFullName(){
       //What code should I write here
       String fullName = "";
       if(notEmpty(firstName))
            fullName = addToName(fullName, firstName);
       if(notEmpty(middleName))
            fullName = addToName(fullName, middleName);
       if(notEmpty(lastName))
            fullName = addToName(fullName, lastName);
       return fullName;
   }

   private boolean notEmpty(String x) {
       return x != null && !x.isEmpty();
   }

   private String addToName(String fullName, String xName) {
       return fullName + xName + " "
   }
}
```